# Is there really no way to auto-kill unresponsive scripts in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

So, in our development team we have a computer attached to a big screen. This computer is used as a dashboard. It's running Firefox in full-screen 24/7. It's automatically rotating all open tabs every few minutes and it's automatically reloading these tabs. It's not a huge amount of tabs, currently only 3.

The problem is that every now and then a script on one of these tabs goes completely wild and totally freezes the entire computer. So it takes roughly 10 minutes to kill Firefox's process and restart it. This is really annoying. It happens every few days.

The content (applications) which these tabs show are not under our control, we can't change anything about them. Our only option is to adapt to them as best as possible.

What I want to do is to make Firefox, instead of showing the "unresponsive script" prompt, to automatically kill the script, without the need for any interaction from the user. I don't care if the script is killed. It's only used to render the page and the page will be reloaded in a few minutes anyway.

The thing is that this "freezing" usually happens over night, slowly consuming the computer's resources more & more, so when we come in the morning it's really frozen deep. Like, just hitting ctrl+alt+f1 to bring up a terminal and log in takes several minutes.

I've googled my ass off trying to find a solution for this, but so far I didn't find any. I want it to simply work for like a month without the need for any intervention.

Comment: Since you can't change the site you're displaying, and you can't fix the browser bugs, maybe you could set up a scheduled task that kills the firefox process and restarts it once a day, maybe around 6am before everyone comes in.

Comment: Although this may not guarantee that it will work, I guess I could give it a try as it doesn't seem as much work. Just need to find out how to auto-start certain tabs when Firefox is run and how to auto-start it in full-screen. But I guess both of these things should be straightforward.

Comment: As you said, it's not a guarantee, but based on the statement that it happens "every few days", then killing and restarting it once a day should prevent it from ever getting into a bad state to begin with.

Comment: There absolutely is a way to kill unresponsive scripts. Because a box pops up saying if you want to terminate a script when it takes too long. I would inspect that and see what its doing and do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could run with [e10s](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Electrolysis) enabled (available in dev edition) and write an addon that instruments tabs and periodically sends messages to them. if they don't respond within a certain timespan you can kill the content process, close all tabs and reopen them.

Since you say it hangs the entire computer you could also limit the memory available to the process and just restart it via a script when it gets killed due to OOM.

Comment: Your solution sounds interesting, I guess it would work. But it also sounds like a bit too much work then I would like to spend on this. So I think I will try RJM's suggestion first.